# URL запросы в C++Builder

Tags: python, c++builder, curl, url

```
connect = psycopg2.connect("host='10.10.10.10' port='8080' user='XXX' dbname='service' password='********'")    
baza = connect.cursor()
baza.execute("SELECT camera FROM camers_list WHERE type = 1 AND (place_full LIKE '%ПАРАМЕТР%' OR place_full LIKE '%ПАРАМЕТР%') AND dateto = (select max(dateto) from camers_list)")
mkad = baza.fetchall()
baza.execute("SELECT camera,dist72 FROM camers_list WHERE type = 1 AND dateto = (SELECT MAX(dateto) FROM camers_list) AND dist72 != -1 ORDER BY dist72")
camers = baza.fetchall()
```

Это код на питоне, пытаюсь перевести в Borland С++. Как лучше это лучше сделать?

Comment: Питон не знаю, но знаю с++ ... Что конкретно нужно сделать?

Comment: URL запрос к базе данных с выносом данных по параметрам в массив.

Comment: Подозреваю, что если та либа питона имеет привязку к с++, то код будет почти такой же

Comment: похож то похож, вопрос в том какой, я сейчас перехожу ток с питона на плюсы, как сделать подключение к базе я понял, а вот как вынести данные не понимаю. Был бы очень благодарен если бы скинули что то похожее.